# Jython standalone jar and packages

Tags: java, python, jython

Is it possible to create a jython standalone (jar) including jython packages (pynum, python-excel, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [Jython FAQ on distribution](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts?highlight=%28standalone%29%7C%28jar%29). Basically, you just need to have the /Lib directory inside the Jython jar. You can add modules there - as long as they are Jython compatible (ie no native part).